# Python: how to move values in an array from some position to another?

Tags: python, arrays

I have an a array of values

```
a = np.array([0,3,4,5,12,3,78,53,52])
```

I would like to move the last three elements in the array starting from the index 3 in order to have

```
a 
array([ 0, 3, 4, 78, 53, 52, 5, 12, 3])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use slicing and concatenation.

```
np.concatenate((a[:3], a[-3:], a[3:-3]))
```

Comment: We just need to perform three number-swap operations. Your solution will will involve making copies of all the other (bigger) chunks of data too. Needless, don't you think?

Answer (score 2):

Try this using `np.delete()` and `np.insert()`:

```
a = np.array([0,3,4,5,12,3,78,53,52])
index = 6
another_index = 0
v = a[index]
np.delete(a,index)
np.insert(a, another_index, v)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just a **number-swapping problem** -- not a numpy problem.

Any solution to this problem that involves numpy functions such as `concatenate`, `delete`, `insert`, or even **slicing**, is **inefficient**, involving unnecessary copying of data.

This should work, with minimum copying of data:

```
a[3],a[4],a[5], a[-3],a[-2],a[-1] = a[-3],a[-2],a[-1], a[3],a[4],a[5]

print(a)
```

Output:

```
[ 0  3  4 78 53 52  5 12  3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting with

```
a = np.array([0,3,4,5,12,3,78,53,52])
```

You can just do:

```
newa=[]
for index, each in enumerate(a):
    if index<3:
        newa.append(a[index])
    else:
        newa.append(a[3+index%6])
```

giving the resulting `newa` to be:

```
[0, 3, 4, 78, 53, 52, 5, 12, 3]
```